# python pip instal apns 0.2.1

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to use [apns-client 0.2.1](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/apns-client/0.2.1) but I only get an error message.

```
22:56:01 $ pip install apnsclient==0.2.1
Collecting apnsclient==0.2.1
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apnsclient==0.2.1 (from versions: 0.1)
No matching distribution found for apnsclient==0.2.1
```

How can I install 0.2.1 version and then save it in requirements.txt? I need it in this way because my hosting use this file too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package is called `apns-client`, notice the dash.

```
pip install apns-client
```